# iPhone Create Lite Version

Tags: iphone, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

Do I need to create a new app in iTunes connect, for a lite version?  I just want to make sure, can't find any articles on it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you plan on releasing a full version and a lite version that are separately downloadable from the app store, you will need to create a separate app for each in iTunes connect.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two fantastic links, I used them both with success:

- [From Full to Lite in Under An Hour](http://gamesfromwithin.com/from-full-to-lite-in-under-an-hour) by Noel - technical one, describes Xcode project settings, targets and building
- [The Right Light](http://struct.ca/2010/the-right-lite/) by Trainyard's developer Matt Rix - much more content and marketing orientated, nonetheless **a must read**

Comment: but how are you going to change target during runtime ??